# Changing Android fonts aspect ratio

Tags: android, fonts

[image: ٍSample of the required output]

I am building an Android application that requires displaying a numeric value in an elongated way as shown above. I have tried to use the `android:scaleY` XML attribute of the text view without success. Any ideas about how to increase the height of a font while leaving the width unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale any text in x or y direction and give certain width to but to
    achieve that you have to provide `margin` at center as text size are wrap but 
    there scale increase from center so by increase margin you can 
    do that only always text should be in center by that and compare scale in 
    both up an down or scale Y and left right for scale X

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="40dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="80dp"
            android:scaleY="12.8"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```